# Get base website URL from input

Tags: php, regex, url, base-url

I have a textbox on my website where peoples can submit url addresses. Most of the time the enter wrong url's like:

```
http://www.website.com?id=1
http://www.website.com/#/gls
http://www.website.com/post/test
```

But I want them to enter their base url, meaning this: http://www.website.com

How can I achieve this considering that I have their url address stored in an `$url` variable?

I have some ideeas but I don't think it's a very good solution. For example I thought at splitting the domain after "." and after that get the domain extension somehow without the rest of the useles code.

Comment: Take a look at `$_SERVER`

Comment: How can this help me at all? $_SERVER has nothing to do with a php variable, nothing. Have you read the question?

Comment: @Diego and ArtisiticPhoenix OP is referring to a *user-inputted* string (not the base URL of the current website).

Comment: @LambdaNinja Thanks bro for backing me up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `parse_url` rather than a regular expression, to take out the parts you need and compare it to what they've entered like this:

```
// Get each part of the URL
$parts = parse_url($url);

// Rebuild the URL with only the scheme and domain (Without path, fragment, query string etc.)
$expected = $parts['scheme'] . '://' . $parts['host'];

// Compare the expected URL with what they user has entered.
if ($expected != $url) {
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: Nice and straightforwards example. +1

Answer (score 2):

You can use the PHP [`parse_url()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) with the `PHP_URL_HOST` parameter.

Like so:

```
parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
```

This will return `www.example.com` for the URL `http://www.example.com/test`.

Alternatively, to include the scheme as well, you can try the following:

```
parse_url($url, PHP_URL_SCHEME) . "://" . parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
```

This will return `http://www.example.com` for the URL `http://www.example.com/test`.

---

If you want to use regular expressions (as you've suggested with the tag) about returning the section before the first `/` (besides in `http://`) or `#` or `?`, any of which are invalid characters in the base url? Any part of the URL after the base would have to start with one of these characters.

Like so:

```
preg_match("/^http:\/\/[^\/\?\#]+/", $url)
```

Answer (score 0):

This version work with https.

The first parenthesis will capture the base url.

```
preg_match("/^(https?:\/\/.+)(\/|#|\?|)/U", $url, $anArray)
// Access to the base url
$anArray[1]
```

Comment: The `/` (backslash) in the middle of the regex has to be escaped, or it will be treated as a delimiter